# How to store a data structure on a hard drive

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

I have made a trie data structure to store contacts in a contact book and need to know how I can make a permanent copy of the trie to my hard drive. I tried serializing the trie object but got the notSerializableException in Java. Is there anyway I can store the trie to any form of secondary memory without deconstructing the data structure and then reonstructing it when I open up my application again.

Comment: store it in a file?

Comment: Well you can always write data to a csv file or txt file easily in java?

Comment: your node and trie class should implement Serializeable interface to serialize Trie on harddisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encountered NotSerializableException, please do as follows:

- Check if all of your classes are **Serializable**
- Be careful with **inner** class. Check if inner class is static, nonstatic inner class cannot be **serialized**.